# Where do these "bonus points" come from?

Tags: discussion

I see this from time to time, in questions where "[bonus points](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=bonus%20points)" are offered by low-rep users and even newbies.

Are they talking out of their tuchis and just parroting something they have seen on another site, or is it really possible...?

The most recent is [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426965/terminology-what-do-you-call-two-words-that-rhyme-but-whose-endings-arent-spel).

If you look at the examples, it is obvious that a bounty was never offered.

Comment: I think it is just a metaphorical expression just to attract users’ attention,  the only way to do it would be to place a bounty later, after 2 days.

Comment: it's just a figure of speech, it's a typical expression used in quizzes or pub quizzes. No one can offer extra rep, but I suppose if an answer is exhaustive the OP will be more likely to accept it, ergo +15 (It's +15 isn't)

Comment: Note: The "bonus" question there is actually irrelevant to English, so I've removed it (while leaving it visible for the benefit of *this* question). It may be removed entirely except from the edit history, in due course.

Comment: To me these sound a lot like "brownie points". https://www.google.com/search?q=define+brownie+points

Answer (score 3):

The *bonus points* here most likely is a figure of speech, like the comments suggest. Think of *[brownie points](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brownie-points)* or [*kudos*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kudos) - they're merely a way of expressing appreciation.

It *could* also refer to bounty giveaways. A 50 rep bounty can be given by this user after waiting the minimum 2 days. They have a 100+ rep. But that extra question, being off-topic, is now removed.

Comment: I think the user might have placed also a 100 rep point bounty despite the  total  low rep.

Comment: @user159691 I don't see any bounty on the post's timeline.

Comment: Yes! but he might have offered more than 50 rep points bounty as you suggest had he been willing and in a position to do that.

Comment: @user159691 Not sure what you meant by that. Anyone would do anything had they been _willing_ and _in a position_ to do it.

Comment: What I mean is that the information you give in your answer is not correct.

Comment: @user159691 Specifically, what is incorrect in it? Let me know so I can correct it.

Comment: @NVZ I disagree with Josh. I think your answer is correct. The phrase “bonus points” is synonymous with “[extra credit](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/141974/55623)”, which phrase a lot of querents use to indicate [a side-question tangentially related to their main question](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20“extra%20credit”). It has nothing to do with rep. A lot of these are new users who may not even be aware of he rep system, and are almost certainly unfamiliar with its finer details, including the bounty mechanism.

Comment: @DanBron Ah, thanks. I think you are right, but just in this user's case, they've been around for 7 years on SO, so they're not all that new to rep system. I don't think they're familiar with bounties though.

Comment: @NVZ I was more talking to Cascabel’s observation that the term is often used by “low rep users and newbies”, not this specific account.

Comment: @DanBron Ah, yes, correct.